# Is it possible to lock SKU field in Magento 1.4.0.1 to prevent further edditing?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Because our warehouse import script crashes if an existing product has two different sku numbers.

Is it possible to set the SKU field to read-only after inital creation?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend to get down to the root of the trouble, instead of sticking plasters.

Comment: Hm... in this case i think the 'root of the trouble' is, that you can edit an SKU number of an existing product... if you have sold some products you should not be able to change it. is my opinion.

Comment: i would prefer to use the sku as an uniq product identifier over multiple applications. and the sku number is more helpfull for the warehouse helpline.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use method "lockAttribute(SattributeCode)" called on product model before rendering admin edit/new view (maybe from some observer).